# Python PySerial read-line timeout

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm using pyserial to communicate with a embedded devise.

```
ser = serial.Serial(PORT, BAUD, timeout = TOUT)
ser.write(CMD)
z = ser.readline(eol='\n')
```

So we send CMD to the device and it replies with an string of varing length ending in a `'\n'`

if the devise cant replay then `readline()` times-out and `z=''`

if the devise is interrupted or crashes will it's sending the data then `readline()` times-out 
and z will be a string without a `'\n'` at the end.

Is there a nice way to check if `readline()` has timed-out other than checking the state of z.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you might like to do is..

```
import re
import time
import serial

def doRead(ser,term):
    matcher = re.compile(term)    #gives you the ability to search for anything
    tic     = time.time()
    buff    = ser.read(128)
    # you can use if not ('\n' in buff) too if you don't like re
    while ((time.time() - tic) < tout) and (not matcher.search(buff)):
       buff += ser.read(128)

    return buff

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ser = serial.Serial(PORT, BAUD, timeout = TOUT)
    ser.write(CMD)
    print doRead(ser,term='\n')
```

Comment: Why do you use a regex? Wouldn't a `if '\n' in buff` be more performant and shorter?

Answer (score 0):

PySerial has [read_until](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read_until) method exactly for this, it reads the serial until an expected sequence is found (‘\n’ by default), the size is exceeded or until timeout occurs.